# Working with Negative Infinity (Vertical) slopes in BlueJ

Tags: java

Everything in my code finally seems right. i'm just having trouble with something tricky.

How do I write a code so that when i enter two points and the slope is `-infinity`, it's identified and the output says `Vertical` and NOT `Negative Slope`.

For example, a Positive Slope OUTPUT would look like:

```
Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point: 3 -2
Enter the x and y coordinates of the second point: 9 2
Distance: 7.211
Positive Slope
```

AND a Vertical would look like:

```
Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point: 4 5
Enter the x and y coordinates of the second point: 4 -3
Distance: 8.000
Vertical
```

AND right now my Vertical Output looks like:

```
Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point: 4 5
Enter the x and y coordinates of the second point: 4 -3
Distance: 8.000
Negative Slope
```

**Here is what my code looks like right now:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineEvaluator
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point: ");
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the x and y coordinates of the second point: ");
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();

        double distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        System.out.printf("Distance: %.3f", distance);

        double slope = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));

        if(slope > 0)
        System.out.println("Positive Slope");
        else if(slope < 0)
        System.out.println("Negative Slope");
        else if(slope == 0)
        System.out.println("Horizontal");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check explicitly if `slope == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. You should do the same for `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

```
    if (slope == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || slope == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
      System.out.println("Vertical");
    else if(slope > 0)
      System.out.println("Positive Slope");
    else if(slope < 0)
      System.out.println("Negative Slope");
    else if(slope == 0)
      System.out.println("Horizontal");
```

Or you can use `Double.isInfinite` :

```
    if (Double.isInfinite(slope))
      System.out.println("Vertical");
    else if(slope > 0)
      System.out.println("Positive Slope");
    else if(slope < 0)
      System.out.println("Negative Slope");
    else if(slope == 0)
      System.out.println("Horizontal");
```